"The right-center part of an area" or "The center-right part of an area"?
I'm learning how to describe a map. How can I call its "right-center" part?


The shop is in the right-center section of the area.
The shop is in the right-central section of the area.
The shop is in the center-right section of the area.
The shop is in the middle-right section of the area.


.....
Feel free to suggest any way to describe it better. Thank you!

Is this a topographic style map with North "up" the page? Or is it more like a map of a mall or shopping center which might not be oriented with North "up"?

The most natural-sounding way to describe such things is using center-right.
That’s the same construction used to describe political positions, based on the left-right metaphor. Consider Today’s Republican Party in Congress retains nearly nobody from the traditional center right that was so strong throughout the mid-twentieth century.

…and although you do include that one in your title, it’s absent from the body of your post. You may wish to edit to add it.

Can I remove "section", just "the center-right of the area"?

@AnIELTSLearner Yes. "in" implies that you're describing a section.

I agree with center-right of the OP's list, but a close alernative could be central-right or middle-right (to go with upper-right and lower-right).
